# Core Plot Axis Labelling with Time

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am trying to label the X-axis in Core Plot with time values in HH:MM:SS format.Now I want it to start from the current system time everytime. So how do we provide a starting time for the X-axis from where labelling should start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved it finally by setting the CPTTimeFormatter reference Date parameter to the desired start UTC Time.

Code Snippet:

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm:ss";

[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

CPTTimeFormatter *timeFormatter = [[CPTTimeFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormatter:dateFormatter];

NSDate *refDate =[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:desiredStartTime];

timeFormatter.referenceDate = refDate;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`labelingOrigin`](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/interface_c_p_t_axis.html#a0efc1ed2cb34c18efa5057e9400b7724) to set the starting label location for most axis labeling policies.

Comment: In case of labelling with time I have provided a reference date for the time formatter which I need to be the starting point ; which however does not work.Setting axis labelling origin would require NSNumber as an arguments in case of starting time what exactly should be passed.

Comment: Providing the reference date for DateFormatter as current system time ; it always starts the labelling from 05:30:00 .

Comment: The labeling origin is the same units as the plot data. Convert the starting time to a number the same way you do with the plot data.

Comment: Won't the starting time be converted to zero if we are setting the plot range say from 0 to 600.

Comment: With a range 0 to 600, wouldn't you want the labels to start at zero? You can set up the label formatter to convert those values to any time you want. It all depends on how you're converting the time values in the plot data to the numbers required by the datasource. Use the same conversion when determining axis labels and plot ranges.

Comment: Will try that out. Any example demonstrating the mapping between time and axis labels ?

Comment: Several of the Core Plot example apps display times in the axis labels, for example, the "Range Plot" and the "Date Plot" in the *Plot Gallery* app.

Comment: Thanks Eric.Will work out through the examples provided.